# "Error: Forbidden" even though service account has function permission access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-cloud-functions, permission-denied, data-pipeline

I am trying to deploy a data ingestion pipeline in Google Cloud Functions.

When I trigger the URL, I get the following error:

> Error: Forbidden
> Your client does not have permission to get URL /entry-point from this server.

I don't understand when am I getting this error because my function's service account has the `cloudfunctions.invoker` role and I am the owner of the project. I even granted the `cloudfunctions.invoker` to my user account but it still not working.

I have managed to make it work by giving the `cloudfunctions.invoker` to allUser, but I would prefer not doing it for safety reasons.

Does someone have an idea of why it doesn't work?

Comment: Your question lacks detail. What are you doing when you "trigger the URL"? I assume that URL is a Cloud Functions function. If the Cloud Functions function is not `allUsers` then the identity of the caller must be authenticated; i.e. you can only `curl` the endpoint with an `Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)` header.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thank you for your answer. By triggering the URL, I mean that I click on the "trigger URL" in the "TRIGGER" section of the function's page. How can I add the ```Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)``` in my ```.gitlab-ci.yml ``` file?

Comment: For a Project Owner, for 1st and 2nd gen Cloud Functions, the Console Trigger should just work because the Console leverages the logged in identity. To call from the command-line, you can `gcloud functions call` **or** you can construct a `curl` command using the function's endpoint and adding `--header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"`. Calling from GitLab is a different question and should be submitted as a new question.

Comment: So there is indeed a problem with the console trigger. Thank you for you help, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Don't forget to add details on the configuration, test and permissions, if it still does not work

Comment: Can you confirm if you were able to fix the issue?

Comment: @AndresFiescoCasasola thank you for your comment, I just post the update as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion from @DazWilkin in the comment, I tried the following command in my terminal and it worked.

```
https://zone-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/entry-point -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"
```

I still don't manage to trigger make it work using the console trigger, but it is fine because my goal is to trigger the function with a request made by Cloud Scheduler.