# "Error: Forbidden" http console trigger doesn't work even though I am the project owner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, triggers, permissions, google-cloud-functions, permission-denied

I deployed a Cloud Function but when I manually click on the Trigger URL in the console trigger I get this error:

> Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL /entry-point from this server.

I don't understand why am I getting this because I am the project owner and I even added the cloudfunctions.invoker role to my user account. A comment from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73706520/error-forbidden-even-though-service-account-has-function-permission-access) confirms that it should work.

Does anyone has an idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure you selected "Allow unauthenticated" when creating your Cloud Function? Thats the only way you'll be able to trigger it by clicking on the link where you're not passing in authentication.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_http_function_invocation

Comment: Can you confirm whether the issue has been resolved from the comments posted in this stack [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73706520/error-forbidden-even-though-service-account-has-function-permission-access)? If yes, please post the resolution steps as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: @ianyoung No I didn't, this is what I want to avoid. I thought that being the owner  of the project would allow me to use the console trigger. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, the cause of the issue is that I didn't allow unauthenticated, and this is the only way to use the control trigger.

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_http_function_invocation) shows how to change this setting.